# Angular ui-select default selected value

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

I am using ui-select in Angular to have a select box in my page. I can search by typing and when I select value, the name will be displayed [Which is fine], and the ng-model has the selected values id[which is also correct]

Now I try to load view of a already saved record. I want the selected box to pre filled.

But it does not!

This is my HTML

```
<ui-select ng-model="vm.product.category">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Type to search">{{ (vm.categories | filter : { id : vm.product.category } : true)[0].name }}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="category.id as category in (vm.categories | filter: {name: $select.search})">
        <span ng-bind-html="category.name | highlight: $select.search"></span>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

Here is my controller,

```
app.controller('productDetailsController', [
    '$scope', 'Product',
    function ($scope, Product) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.product = {};
        vm.categories = [{name: "General", id: "1"}, {name: "Product", id: "2"}]

        Product.get({id: id}).$promise.then(function (data) {
            vm.product = data.data;
        }, function (error) {
            alert(error);
        });
    }
]);
```

When I load record from database my model () has the ID. but I want the name to be displayed to the user.

How can I do this? WHat am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.select']);
app.service('myservice', ['$timeout', '$q',
  function($timeout, $q) {
    this.getData = function() {
      var defer = $q.defer();
      //Here, $timeout corresponds to $http
      $timeout(function() {
        defer.resolve({
          'data': {
            product_name: "Galaxy S3",
            product_description: "Galaxy S3 desc",
            category: 1,
            is_active: true
          }
        });
      }, 1000);
      return defer.promise;
    }
  }
]);
app.controller('productDetailsController', ['$scope', 'myservice',
  function($scope, myservice) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.product = {};
    vm.categories = [{
      name: "General",
      id: "1"
    }, {
      name: "Product",
      id: "2"
    }];

    myservice.getData().then(function(data) {
      vm.product = data.data;
    });

  }
]);
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-select/0.11.2/select.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-select/0.11.2/select.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular-sanitize.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="productDetailsController as vm">
  <ui-select ng-model="vm.product.category">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Type to search">{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="category.id as category in vm.categories | filter: {name: $select.search}">
      <div ng-bind="category.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes I do assign `vm.product.category` a key when the data is loaded. When I populate `vm.product` with data from database, I don't see the Category name for the given ID in the selector.

Comment: what data contains?

Comment: It will be more helpful to understand your issue.

Comment: I have this,

`data['data'] = {product_name: "Galaxy S3", 
product_description: "Galaxy S3 desc", 
category: 1, 
is_active: true}`

in data I send other keys such as response status, response msg... etc...

Comment: Product.get({id: id}).$promise , don't get what is $promise. Can you share your Product Service code. And please check .then has executed or not.

Comment: Actually I get the product result to the `vm.product`. Text boxes refer `vm.product.product_name` getting the value from the database. I will share my Product service. Please give me some hours.

Comment: This is my Product service code,

`app.factory('Product', function ($resource) {
    return $resource(base_url + 'api/product/:id', {}, {});
});`